# How to solve multiclass format not supported ROC curve error?

Tags: machine-learning

This is a demand forecasting dataset.

```
x=dataset.drop("units_sold",axis=1)
y=dataset["units_sold"]

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(x,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc=StandardScaler()

x_train=sc.fit_transform(x_train)
x_test=sc.transform(x_test)

from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
classifier_lor=LogisticRegression()
classifier_lor.fit(x_train,y_train)

LogisticRegression()
y_pred_lor=classifier_lor.predict(x_test)
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve,auc
fpr,tpr,thresold=roc_curve(y_test,y_pred_lor)
```

This code gives the below error.
I tried lot of different types but i got the same multiclasserror in juyter.
How to overcome this error.
can any one tell me the solution?

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-35e3e86a427e> in <module>
----> 1 fpr,tpr,thresold=roc_curve(y_test,y_pred_lor)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py in roc_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label, sample_weight, drop_intermediate)
    773 
    774     """
--> 775     fps, tps, thresholds = _binary_clf_curve(
    776         y_true, y_score, pos_label=pos_label, sample_weight=sample_weight)
    777 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\_ranking.py in _binary_clf_curve(y_true, y_score, pos_label, sample_weight)
    537     if not (y_type == "binary" or
    538             (y_type == "multiclass" and pos_label is not None)):
--> 539         raise ValueError("{0} format is not supported".format(y_type))
    540 
    541     check_consistent_length(y_true, y_score, sample_weight)

ValueError: multiclass format is not supported
```

Comment: It is not directly possible. From the scikit-learn docs: "ROC curves are typically used in binary classification..to extend ROC curve and ROC area to multi-label classification... binarize the output. One ROC curve can be drawn per label, but one can also draw a ROC curve by considering each element of the label indicator matrix as a binary prediction (micro-averaging).
Another evaluation measure for multi-label classification is macro-averaging, which gives equal weight to the classification of each label." https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html

Answer (score 0):

It is simply what the error is saying. Multi-class outputs (i.e. a `y` vector of labels where each label is a vector) is ot supported from the function ROC curve. This is not because they haven't bothered implementing it for the multi-class case, but rather because even the theoretical ROC curve is actually mathematically undefined with multiple classes.

I suggest implementing micro-averaged ROC curve or macro-averaged ROC. Another option is to instead plot a ROC curve for every class. Each one of these options is different from the others and neither is necessarily correct. you just have to know what you are doing and what your plot is actually showing. Some more info can be found [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/15989/micro-average-vs-macro-average-performance-in-a-multiclass-classification-settin). Code for a macro-averaged ROC curve is below:

```
def macro_roc(test_y, predictions, n_classes):
    fpr = dict()
    tpr = dict()
    roc_auc = dict()
    for i in range(n_classes):
        fpr[i], tpr[i], _ = roc_curve(test_y[:, i], predictions[:, i])
        roc_auc[i] = auc(fpr[i], tpr[i])

    all_fpr = np.unique(np.concatenate([fpr[i] for i in range(n_classes)]))

    mean_tpr = np.zeros_like(all_fpr)
    for i in range(n_classes):
        mean_tpr += np.interp(all_fpr, fpr[i], tpr[i])

    mean_tpr /= n_classes

    fpr["macro"] = all_fpr
    tpr["macro"] = mean_tpr
    roc_auc["macro"] = auc(fpr["macro"], tpr["macro"])

    return fpr, tpr, roc_auc
```